# PHP compare titles with another title

Tags: php, string, wordpress, loops, strpos

I am working on a function which compares a title of a post to a list of titles (of products in my website).

It is for building a simple advertise system in my own websites which watches the title of current post and compares it with the titles of the products in my website.

If it gets a match, the system needs to cut the product title string from the post title and removes the rest.

**Example:**

Current title: A brand new mountainbike!

List of titles:

1. Refrigerator
2. Table
3. Mountainbike
4. Book
5. Laptop

So my system needs to watch the title: "A brand new mountainbike!", loop it trough the product titles and if it matches "Mountainbike", it needs to stop the loop and cut "A brand new" off.

So I only have the string: "mountainbike".

**My code (I build in Wordpress):**

```
    $current_title = get_the_title(); // "A brand new mountainbike!"
    $titles = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'products', 'posts_per_page' => 100 ) ); // List of titles
    if( $titles->have_posts() ) {
        while( $titles->have_posts() ) {
            $titles->the_post();
            $title = get_the_title(); // The product title from the list
            if( strpos( $current_title, $title ) ) {
                // Here I need to cut the product from the title
                $found = strpos( $current_title, $title );
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: try using stripos(), its case insensitive... and match it with the !== false operator, because returning 0 should be a positive match

Comment: have a look on [`strcasecmp`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php)

Comment: Both thanks for the comments. I will try!

Comment: Or you can try and use [preg_match('/mountainbike/i',$current_title,$match)](http://pt1.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) and `$match` would hold your matched key. Notice the **i** making it case-insensitive

Comment: Thanks, this works, but $match returns an array?

Comment: @MoshMage Oh and it matches wrong because print_r($match); returns Array ( [0] => Refrigerator ). So the first of the list and not mountainbike.

Comment: @MoshMage Sorry this was a fault in my wordpress loop. I needed to reset the loop after.

Comment: @Robbert I'm guessing you'd have to loop through the list of titles against the `$current_title` -- something like `foreach($listOfTitles as $regTitle) { if (preg_match("/{$regTitle}/i",$current_title,$match) !== false) { // current_item_title_of_list_of_title exists in current_title } }`

Comment: @MoshMage Yes, that's what I need. But for some reason I doesn't get a match. My print_r($match); returns an empty array() now..

Comment: `var_dump()`s all the way and debug your variables; Check for any errors or something as I wrote the code in this tiny response window, there might be typos or something might be amiss. Other than that, IDK whats going on - if it was matching before it should match now

Comment: @MoshMage It was matching before, because I did something wrong in my Wordpress loop, so $current_title and $regtitle always where the same.

Comment: I think, its because of break. echo it in loop and see.

Comment: @MoshMage I removed !== false, and now it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to MoshMage, this piece of code solved my problem. The `$match` variable now holds the product name.

```
$current_title = get_the_title();
$titles = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'products', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
if( $titles->have_posts() ) {
   while( $titles->have_posts() ) {
        $titles->the_post();
        $title = get_the_title();
        if( preg_match('/' . $title . '/i', $current_title, $matched ) ) {
            $match = $matched[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

strpos() is case sensitive so that's why "Mountainbike" is not found in "A brand new mountainbike!".

Change your condition to:

```
if( stripos( $current_title, $title) !== false ) {
```

- use **stripos** which is case insensitive
- and also use **!==** false because if you don't and the character would be found on position 0 then you would thing there wasn't a match - for more info see ["Return values" section of php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php)

Whole code:

```
 $current_title = get_the_title(); // "A brand new mountainbike!"
    $titles = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'products', 'posts_per_page' => 100 ) );      // List of titles
    if( $titles->have_posts() ) {
        while( $titles->have_posts() ) {
            $titles->the_post();
            $title = get_the_title(); // The product title from the list
            if( stripos($current_title, $title) !== false ) {
                // Here I need to cut the product from the title
                $found = $title;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work. Maybe because I use it in the loop so? And then it the following title returns false, the variable doesn't get set?

Comment: I think instead of

`if( stripos( $current_title, $title !== false ) ) {`

you should use

`if( stripos( $current_title, $title) !== false ) {`

Comment: I've updated my answer - added whole code (see I've also changed the line with $found = $title;) and also fixed the issue with )